# Ошибка “Fixed Width Constraints May Cause Clipping”

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

Пытался исправить ошибку этими способами https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122691/xcode-9-fixed-width-constraints-may-cause-clipping-and-other-localization-wa , но вылазеет новая ошибка (на скрине в левом нижнем углу обведена). Подскажите, как убрать ... 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CTDA1yg53DhcThwaPYKuulrvlIQSvBj2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ширину ставлю = вылазеет "Fixed width constraints may cause clipping", ставлю >= пропадает первое предуприждение, но вылазеет "Leading constraint is missing, which may cause overlapping with other views".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну это warning, а не ошибка, так что не критично.
Можете побороть несколькими способами:

1. Сделать как предлагает - поставить >= и добавить leading constraint
2. Убрать Title и задавать его программно
3. Добавить View нужного размера, а в нее уже поместить кнопку, которой сделать размеры равные этой View и отцентрировать в ней:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Вынести сториборд из папки .lproj

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Добавлять кнопку программно.
6. Игнорировать.